# How to update multiple table from same form?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to update two tables from the same form. i.e. updating task table and check_list table.

This is for laravel updating database. I've tried the solution from multiple questions that were asked before.

// this is my function in a controller.

```
public function task_update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $task = tasks::findOrFail($id);
    $input = $request->all();
    $task->fill($input)->save();
    $check_list['remarks'] = Input::get('status');
    $check_list->save();
    notify()->success('Task has been updated');

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Actually, I am passing the data with id of task to the function and want to update the table of check_list of same task_id. ?

I want to update the check_list table too, but instead it adds new row as a new data.

Comment: This won't work. You are calling `save()` on an array?

Comment: Thank you for ur response sir, can u suggest me to work on ?

Comment: Where is `$check_list` coming from?

Comment: Thank you for your response sir, i got the solution , I jst added following code to my function :
 $check_list= check_list::where('task_id', $id)->update(['remarks' => $request->input('status')]);